Kerberos Authentication for multiple domains with no common dns
We have created a container image and are running our playbooks through that execution environment.
There are 4 domains:

example1 domain has ex1 IP
example2 and example3 are currently working under the same ex2 IP
example4 domain has ex3 IP

My krb5.conf:
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = example1.net
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true

[realms]
EXAMPLE1.NET = {
    kdc = HOSTNAME.example1.net
    admin_server = HOSTNAME.example1.net
}
EXAMPLE2.NET = {
    kdc = HOSTNAME.example2.net
    admin_server = HOSTNAME.example2.net
}
EXAMPLE3.NET = {
    kdc = HOSTNAME.example3.net
    admin_server = HOSTNAME.example3.net
}
EXAMPLE4.NET = {
    kdc = HOSTNAME.example4.net
    admin_server = HOSTNAME.example4.net
}

[domain_realm]
.example1.net = EXAMPLE1.NET
example1.net = EXAMPLE1.NET
.example2.net = EXAMPLE2.NET
example2.net = EXAMPLE2.NET
.example3.net = EXAMPLE3.NET
example3.net = EXAMPLE3.NET
.example4.net = EXAMPLE4.NET
example4.net = EXAMPLE4.NET


This is my resolv.conf:
nameserver ex1
nameserver ex2
nameserver ex3
The Problem:
If I alter resolv.conf, for example, by keeping ex1 in the 2nd line, it is not able to connect, and I get the error: "Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'example1' while getting initial credentials."
If I move ex1 back to the 1st line, it works. However, if I move ex3 (which corresponds to example4) to the 3rd line, it does not work. If I keep it in the 1st line, it pings successfully.
Please help! It's been more than a month, and I have not been able to resolve this.
your text
I'm able to nslookup, and kinit is working for all the domains. I have tried using the /etc/hosts file, but it’s not working, so I am just trying with resolv.conf.
I’ve tried altering the resolv.conf, but if the 1st nameserver works, then the 3rd one does not.

It sounds like it's not a Kerberos issue, it's purely a DNS issue.
You cannot "stack" nameservers in resolv.conf if they 'know' different data. The system treats them as equal alternatives, and if the 1st nameserver provides a reply – even if that reply is "Domain not found" – the system will not bother trying the 2nd or 3rd nameserver; because it did receive a reply from the first one.
Normally the "no common DNS" problem would be solved by setting up DNS delegations ('NS' records), just like it is done for public Internet domain names – nobody puts "nameserver ns1.google.com, nameserver ns1.facebook.com, etc" in their resolv.conf – but if that's not an option in your case (let's say the names don't correspond to real domain registrations), there are ways to set it up internally.
That is, start by deploying your own DNS resolver server (Unbound would be my initial choice, but Dnsmasq or BIND9 can work too); make sure it can resolve various Internet domains; then configure it to have "stub zones" or "forward zones" for each of the internal domains you need.



For example, in Unbound:
or in BIND 9:




stub-zone:    name: example1.com    stub-addr: 192.168.1.53
zone "example1.com" {    type static-stub; /* not 'stub' */    server-addresses { 192.168.1.53; };};



And then you have a common DNS server that is able to resolve everything through a single resolv.conf nameserver entry.

Hi, Thank you for your reply, I'm trying with the dnsmasq method, I have added the primary and secondary dns in the file and in resolv.conf I have added 127.0.0.1 but in container its taking 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 Im ot able to figure this out. Getting the same error.
